# Is Bottle gourd and white pumpkin same?

Tags: vegetables

I would like to know whether the Bottle gourd and white pumpkin both are same?

I found no answer in googling.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "white pumpkin"? [Google image search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=white+pumpkin&tbm=isch) just look like, well, white pumpkins, nothing at all like [bottle gourd (calabash)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabash). Maybe something like this ["white cushaw pumpkin"](http://www.reimerseeds.com/white-cushaw-pumpkins.aspx)? It appears to be a variety of [cucurbita argyrosperma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_argyrosperma) - does that look like what you're asking about?

Comment: @Jefromi i recently relocated to other region where many nationalities live in. In hyper market, they labeled it as 'White Pumpkin', It looks like Bottle Gourd. So I googles, is there a vegetable called white pumpkin in any other nations, no idea what it is. thats why posted here

Comment: Okay. Without a photo or anything, I'm afraid people are just going to have to guess what you mean by "white pumpkin" - made worse by the fact that they're not from where you are, and the name may have gone through translation - so I'm going to put this on hold. We'd be happy to help, but we don't really want questions where the only possible answers are guesses.

Comment: @Jefromi I have added pic now

Comment: Are you willing to cut it in half so we can see what it looks like inside? (I'll go ahead and reopen, either way.)

Comment: @Jefromi I dont have broken piece images right now. Inside It was like cucmber. Some seeds and soften stuffs. You know, no other vegetables confuesed me like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture and your description "Inside It was like cucmber. Some seeds and soften stuffs", I would say that it is most likely a zucchini. Zucchini come in white (which is actually a pale green), green (which is pine green) and yellow, and the inside looks cucumber-like, although it is not as pleasant to bite into while raw. A further clue would be the hardness of the rind - zucchini slices as easily as a cucumber, while other related plants (including gourds) have a rather hard outer rind which requires some pressure to split.

If it is not a zucchini, there is probably no better way to classify it. There are tons of cucurbitas and hybrids between them, and cooks don't have precise names for all, only for the most commonly eatem ones. So "pumpkin" might be the best you are left with. You can of course also say "white pumpkin" if this is the preferred name regionally, but don't be surprised if you ask somebody from a different region for a "white pumpkin" and you get either a puzzled look or a random pumpkin-related plant with whitish skin.